# What's the meaning of right inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

For a given matrix $A \in R^{m \times n}$, it shows 4 subspace: row space, col space, null space and left null space.

When $rank(A) = n$, $A$ has a left inverse. When $rank(A) = m$, $A$ has a right inverse.

$A$ can be seen as a function from $R^n$ to col space.

$x$ and $y$ are different vectors in row space and $x - y$ should also be in row space. 
If they are mapped to the same value in col space, then $x-y$ is in the null space, which leads to a contradiction, since row space is perpendicular to the null space. So $A$ is injective.

When $rank(A) = n$, $R^n$ equals to row space, so it's a bijective function.

Then the left inverse matrix can be seen as an inverse function which is from col space to $R^n$. $A^{-1}_{left}A = I^{m \times m}$ means composing a function with its inverse will get the identity function.

But how about the right inverse matrix. $AA^{-1}_{right} = I^{n \times n}$?

Comment: Two remarks: First, the function will not be bijective, unless $m = n$. Second, the matrix $I$ is not the same in both cases, one time it is the $n \times n$ identity matrix, one time it is the $m \times m$ one. I would suggest to make this clear, e.g. by calling them $I_n$ and $I_m$.

Comment: @Shuumatsu: Note that $rank(A) \leq \min(m,n)$.

Comment: @Dirk Thanks for your commenting.  More details are added to show why I think its bijective. Can you show me where goes wrong?

Comment: My answer give an example where it is not bijective.

Comment: @LeeMosher sry for the late reply. Because I'm new to linear algebra, I need some time to ponder your explanation. But it seems that your answer doesn't mention the left inverse. If you are saying that "When $rank(A) = m$, $A$ is not bijective" and my proof for "$A$ is bijective when $rank(A) = n$" is true?

Comment: I do not discuss the left inverse in my answer, because your discussion in your post is good. The question that you posed in the last line of your post is the question that I have answered: "But how about the right inverse matrix. $AA^{-1}_{right} = I^{n \times n}$?" I believe that is also the intent of the comment of @Dirk, perhaps he can confirm.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that "the" right inverse might not be unique. For example, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, which defines a linear transformation $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^1$ given by the formula $f(x,0)=x$, has many right inverses: each of them has the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ y \end{pmatrix}$.

In the special case where $n \ge m$ and $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $m$, there is a unified picture for all of the right inverses of $A$ which goes like this.

In $\mathbb R^n$ consider $ker(A)$, the kernel of the matrix $A$, consisting of all column vectors $v \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $Av=0$. Consider an $n \times m$ right inverse $B$, so $AB=I$. Consider $col(B) \subset \mathbb R^n$, also known as the image of $B$. One can see without too much trouble that $ker(A)$ and $col(B)$ form complementary subspaces of $V$: every vector in $V$ can be expressed uniquely as the sum of a vector in $ker(A)$ and a vector in $col(B)$. The unified picture is that the right inverses of $A$ correspond bijectively with the subspaces of $V$ that are complementary to $ker(A)$.

In the example above, the kernel of the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is the $y$-axis which is the subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ spanned by the column vector $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Each of the right inverse matrices of $A$, i.e. each of the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ y \end{pmatrix}$, corresponds to a complementary subspace of the $y$-axis, namely the non-vertical line spanned by the column vector $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ y \end{pmatrix}$.